# Application to access Twitter data and Retrieving trends

Tags: json, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

**Input:**

```
CONSUMER_KEY =  '3zu*************BClmA'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'pQ************vgJmrysYYWGwSSwA0HzFvB'
OAUTH_TOKEN = '2431620*****************Z9kOlXGWgj9U9hJNSZlAAP'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'a**************9j7aJsXqLmOcsbm'
auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                           CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
#print twitter_api




WORLD_WOE_ID = 1
US_WOE_ID = 23424977


world_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=WORLD_WOE_ID)
us_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=US_WOE_ID)

print world_trends
print
print us_trends
```

**Output:**

```
<twitter.api.Twitter object at 0x7fae2a3fa750>
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tw1.py", line 22, in <module>
    world_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=WORLD_WOE_ID)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter/api.py", line 239, in __call__
    return self._handle_response(req, uri, arg_data, _timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter/api.py", line 270,in              handle_response
    raise TwitterHTTPError(e, uri, self.format, arg_data)
twitter.api.TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 401 for URL: 1.1/trend/place.json           using parameters: (id=1&oauth_consumer_key=3zuNBJp5pSNsL2TQdBClmA&oauth_nonce=2012443237312860371&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1396954063&oauth_token=2431620524-S7HkBF47N49xLiqKlZ9kOlXGWgj9U9hJNSZlAAP&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=7%2FSvFNAnLw9xToRMxr97d9eaPL4%3D)
details: {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
```

Does anybody know why is this error happening?

Comment: Man please dont show your twitter secret tokens like this. Now you have to generate new

Comment: What ERROR? clarify it

Comment: {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}

Comment: hey just resolved the issue @poomrokc  when i generated new keys .

Answer (score 0):

The error `401` means that the request was unauthorized per the Twitter [Error Codes & Responses](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses) page.  There are two types of [authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth)--application-specific and OAuth.  You're using OAuth:

```
auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                           CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
```

This means that either your request was bad or your authentication credentials were.  Looking again at the Error Codes & Responses page linked above, an error code of `32` like you see here:

```
details: {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
```

Means that there's probably something wrong with your authentication credentials.  First, check to make sure that your application has the proper permissions (i.e. read/write) based on what you're trying to do.  You appear to just be getting trends so that should be fine.  Try regenerating your API keys/access tokens on your application page on your [Twitter app page](https://apps.twitter.com/) and you should be all set!